# Validation with Validator.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using Bootstrap and http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ to validate the forms.

I've got the form to validate on a button click rather then submit.

```
$(".registrantBtn").click(function(){
    $('#registrantForm').validator('validate');

});
```

But now I'm trying to be able to tell in jquery when the form is valid and when it's not. I need to continue to the next tab when it's valid, I'm imagining something like:

```
    $(".registrantBtn").click(function(){
       $('#registrantForm').validator('validate');
       if(valid)
       {
         // Do this Stuff
       }
       else
       {
         // Do nothing, let the defaults of bootstrap-validator take over
       }
    });
```

I've dug through the documentation on the website but haven't been able to find anything at all.

Thank you for the help.

As requested, my entire JS file for this is below:

[Renew.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gglmixbdxj3d7e/renew.js?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can use these event to do that . Or you can create a boolean variable . It's default false . When the validator is valid . Change it . 
P/s : You have to create a method to access variable when you are outside of this method .

```
    $('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
  }
})
```

Or you can use some events in the end of  http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator page . 
The `submit` event is only called when you click the button to submit the form . You can change submit event to `valid.bs.validator` . This one is called when the validator is valid

Comment: I clicked the button and it did my else statement. It was invalid. I changed 'submit' to 'valid.bs.validator'

Comment: Can you give me the js file . I will test it .

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to validate . But chrome said : " mask() it not a function " . Can you give also html code ??? I can't understand

Comment: Just get rid of that. It masks a phone number to be formatted right.